# Filter channels to only those that user is moderating

Tags: getstream-io

I am having a setup where I need to show channels based on whether id the user is an admin of the group or not. To flag user as admin, I promote the user as a moderator.

I have a view that I would need to show only the list of channels that the user is currently moderating. Is there a way to filter that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to track this as part of channels' custom data (ie. {moderatorId}) and then use that attribute to match a query.

Track moderatorId on channel data

```
const channel = client.channel('messaging', 'travel', {
    moderatorId: 42,
});

channel.update();
```

Retrieve moderated channels:

```
const filter = { moderatorId: 42 };
const sort = { last_message_at: -1 };
const options = {
  state: true,
  watch: true
};

const channels = await authClient.queryChannels(filter, sort, options);
```